# Search content from main site from SharePoint add-in

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365, sharepoint-hosted-app

Hi I have a SharePoint addin deployed onto a SharePoint dev site. I want it so that I am able to see results from the dev site. I have tried editing the search settings and query settings but nothing shows up .

EDIT: I am using the default search bar, i have implemented it as such:

```
<div title="Type your question here" style="margin-right:0%;margin-top:-2%;padding-left:27%;">
    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox"  />
</div>
```